# Errors in reporting parameters while using cvThreshold

Tags: c++, opencv, graphics

When I used cvThreshold, the compiler always reported the following error.

> error C2664: “double cvThreshold(const CvArr *,CvArr *,double,double,int)”: 无法将参数 1 从“cv::Mat”转换为“const CvArr *”

This is a character segmentation task，Operating environment VS 2013,Opencv 3.4.1.

```
int main()
{

    std::string pattern_jpg = "C:\\Users\\WZW\\desktop\\images\\*.jpg"; 

    std::vector<cv::String> image_files;
    cv::glob(pattern_jpg, image_files);
    if (image_files.size() == 0) {
        cout << "No image files.jpg" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    for (unsigned int frame = 0; frame < image_files.size(); ++frame) 
{

        double otsuThreshold;
        Mat srcImage = cv::imread(image_files[frame], cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
        Mat srcImageGray;                      
        Mat otsuImage;
        otsuThreshold = OTSU(srcImageGray);
        cvThreshold(srcImageGray, otsuImage, otsuThreshold, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);


        imshow("1", otsuImage);
        waitKey(0);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output of images.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is causing your error, but it looks like you never actually initialize srcImageGray.  srcImage is already in grayscale so you can just use that instead.

Hope that helps, but I have never seen an error message like that before.

Comment: Thanks, I found that the mistake was that I had misused the binary function and the problem had been solved....